# Send postfix mail to Java application running on Tomcat

Tags: java, protocols, localhost, postfix-mta

I have a Postfix mail server, and I want to forward my received emails to my application written in Java and running on a Tomcat web server.

As far as I know, it is possible to forward the whole email (head, body, everything) to a port on localhost, where both the mail server and my application is running.

But I don't have any idea how to achieve this. I assume to a http server like Tomcat I cannot send this data in plain (postfix does not wrap it into a http package), so maybe I have to write another daemon process to receive the data from postfix, wrap it into http, and send this to my application?

I'm a bit confused, and have never been a specialist of protocols and these kind of things.

Please someone explain how can I solve the problem above!

Thank you in advance,
Balázs

Comment: okay, so what I did is creating a new application separated from the one running on Tomcat.
this app is listening to a port for a stream and trying to parse it as a MIME message with mime4j (very easy to use, doing fantastic job). if the stream is successfully parsed, i can get the information needed from the TO address (eg. which wall to post a message), the FROM email address has to be obviously a user's address in my system.
then i reuse the parts of my Tomcat app as JARs, and do the same as the user would be logged in, so i insert the conent of the email to the DB with this new app.